# How to change the style of components by their attributes?

Tags: java, css, javafx, pseudo-class

I want to display different labels in javafx and i want to style them depending on their text. I added a css file and set the class of the Labels. I then checkd the fxml and found out that the text is saved in the text attribute.

I looked into normal css and found out that you can there change the style by the attributes. You need to use [] for this. I tried this in my code and it didnt work.

My Code: 
FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="controller">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@../css/loadingScreen.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
    <Label styleClass="field" text="1" />
    <Label styleClass="field" text="2" />
    <Label styleClass="field" text="3" />
</HBox>
```

CSS:

```
.field {
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
    -fx-pref-height: 64px;
    -fx-min-width: 64px;
    -fx-pref-width: 64px;
    -fx-min-height: 64px;
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}

.field[text="1"]{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.field[text="2"]{
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}

.field[text="3"]{
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

i tried the same with normal css and html and it worked there.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.field[text="1"]{
    background-color: red;
}

.field[text="2"]{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.field[text="3"]{
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="field" text="1" >1</div>
<div class="field" text="2" >2</div>
<div class="field" text="3" >3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What do i have to do to make this work in fxml?

Comment: Don't believe JavaFX-CSS supports what you want. Why not give each `Label` a certain [style class](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getStyleClass()) based on the text? Or if you only have approximately three labels, each styled uniquely, you could set [their ID](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getId()) instead.

Comment: thx for the answer i am probably going to use a style for each textvalue. The original reason why i wanted to set the style by attribute was, that if i would change the text it would also automatically change the style without needing to change the class.

Comment: Slaw is right, see this section of the CSS Regerence Guide starting at the list: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph Right now you do not seem to update the `Label`s so I'm unsure why you don't simply work with ids/style classes to "tell the `Label`s appart" in CSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I would change the text it would also automatically change the
>   style

**Option 1:** control style by id
You can achieve it by using a custom label that changes style when changing text. I'll demonstrat it by changing the label's id. This simplified example uses the text as id :

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class CustomLabel extends Label{

    public CustomLabel() {
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setPrefSize(50, 25);
    }

    void setTextAndId(String s){
        super.setText(s);
        /*To keep this demo simple and clear id is changed.
          If used, care must be taken to keep id unique. 
          Using setStyle() or PseudoClass should be preferred 
        */
        setId(s); 
    }
}
```

The custom label can be used in an fxml (`Root.fxml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import tests.CustomLabel?>

<StackPane fx:id="root" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="tests.Controller">
   <children>
      <CustomLabel fx:id="cLabel" text="&quot;&quot;" />
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

A simple css that changes background color based on id (`Root.css`):

```
#1{
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
#2{
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
#3{
    -fx-background-color: green;
    -fx-text-fill: yellow;
}
```

Test class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LabelCssTest extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Root.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And test controller :

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    CustomLabel cLabel;
    @FXML Parent root;
    private static final int MIN_VALUE = 1, MAX_VALUE = 3;
    private int counter = MIN_VALUE;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Root.css").toExternalForm());
        cLabel.setTextAndId(String.valueOf(counter++));

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        pause.setOnFinished(event ->{
            cLabel.setTextAndId(String.valueOf(counter++));
            if(counter > MAX_VALUE) {
                counter = MIN_VALUE;
            }
            pause.play();
        });
        pause.play();
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** control style by changing style-class
Use the same test class as option 1.

`Root.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane fx:id="root" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tests.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="label" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="&quot; &quot;" />
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

`Root.css`:

```
.style1{
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
.style2{
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
.style3{
    -fx-background-color: green;
     -fx-text-fill: yellow;
}
```

And controller:

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Controller {

    @FXML Label label;
    @FXML Parent root;

    private static final int MIN_VALUE = 1, MAX_VALUE = 3;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty counter = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

         root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Root.css").toExternalForm());
        counter = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        counter.addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            label.getStyleClass().clear();
            label.getStyleClass().add("style"+counter.get());
        });
        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(()->String.valueOf(counter.get()), counter));
        counter.set(1);

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        pause.setOnFinished(event ->{
            counter.set(counter.get() >= MAX_VALUE ? MIN_VALUE : counter.get()+1);
            pause.play();
        });
        pause.play();
    }
}
```

**Option 3:** control style by using `PseudoClass`:
Changes from option 2: 
`Root.css`:

```
.root:style1 #label{
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
.root:style2 #label{
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
.root:style3 #label{
    -fx-background-color: green;
    -fx-text-fill: yellow;
}
```

And controller:

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Controller {

    @FXML Label label;
    @FXML Parent root;

    private static final int MAX_VALUE = 3;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty counter = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Root.css").toExternalForm());
        counter = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        counter.addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            updateStates();
        });

        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(()->String.valueOf(counter.get()), counter));
        counter.set(1);

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        pause.setOnFinished(event ->{
            counter.set(counter.get() >= MAX_VALUE ? 1 : counter.get()+1);
            pause.play();
        });
        pause.play();
    }

    private void updateStates() {
        for( int index = 1; index <= MAX_VALUE; index++){
            PseudoClass pc = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("style"+String.valueOf(index));
            root.pseudoClassStateChanged(pc, index == counter.get()  ? true : false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ... shouldn't the id be unique across the document?

Comment: thx for the suggestion i implemented this and it works fine. i changed it a bit. it changes the class instead of the id because the customlabel can have the same text as other custom labels.

Comment: Changing the style class or using pseudo class is certainly better. The posted technique was chosen for clarity and simplicity.

Comment: @kleopatra  You are right. hence the comment "//you may want to implement some logic here".  This simplified demo does not violate it, but I did improve the comment wording. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the background color of a `Label`, depending on the text, you can also just create a method like this, and call it for each `Label`, when you need it.

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;    

private void backgroundColorTextDependent(Label label) {
        if (label.getText().equals("1")) {
            label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        } else if (label.getText().equals("2")) {
            label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        } else if (label.getText().equals("3")) {
            label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        } else {
            label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        }
```